# Create new session for every request for Flask-Sqlalchemy

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have two servers behind a load balancer. If a PUT or POST transaction is being run on one server, the other server will not be able to query the latest data i.e.

Request 1: Change vehicle's name, for id 2, from Car 001 to Car 101.

Request 2: Get vehicle's name for id 2 and it will show Car 001 until a few minutes then it will change to Car 101.

My folder structure is like this:

- -api
- --helpers
- --models
- ---init.py
- ---vehicle.py
- --resources
- ---init.py
- ---vehicles.py

Here is the code for init.py in models:

```
from flask import Flask

from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_marshmallow import Marshmallow

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = "url"
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_POOL_RECYCLE'] = 5 
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_POOL_SIZE'] = 10

db = SQLAlchemy(app)
ma = Marshmallow(app)
```

Here is the vehicle model:

```
import arrow, json, uuid
import jwt
from datetime import datetime
import datetime as dt
from functools import wraps


from api.models import db, ma

from api.titan.v1.models.vehicle_state import VehicleState


class Vehicle(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer(), primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(300), index=True)
    createdAt = db.Column(db.DateTime)
    plateNumber = db.Column(db.String(300))
```

Here is the vehicle requests handling:

```
import arrow, json, uuid, pytz
import requests
from datetime import datetime

from flask_restful import reqparse, abort, Api, Resource
from werkzeug.exceptions import BadRequest
from flask import request, jsonify

from api.models import db


class Vehicles(Resource):

    def get(self, vehicle_id=None):

        response_object = {
            'object': 'vehicle',
            'verb': 'GET',
            'timestamp': arrow.utcnow().timestamp
        }

       if vehicle_id is None:
            vehicles = db.session.query(Vehicle).filter_by(companyId=user['companyId']).all()
            response_object['data'] = [schema.dump(i).data for i in vehicles]  

        else:
            vehicle = db.session.query(Vehicle).filter_by(id=vehicle_id, companyId=user['companyId']).first()
            response_object['data'] = schema.dump(vehicle).data


        return response_object, 200


    def put(self, vehicle_id):


        data = request.get_json()

        response_object = {
            'object': 'vehicle',
            'verb': 'PUT',
            'timestamp': arrow.utcnow().timestamp,
        }

        vehicle = db.session.query(Vehicle).filter_by(id=vehicle_id).first()
        vehicle.name = data['name']
        db.session.commit()

        response_object['data'] = vehicle


        return response_object, 200
```

Comment: Are you using MySQL? Your put method handler seems to be missing a call to commit.

Comment: Yes, I am using MySQL and I edited the example to show db.session.commit().

Comment: I'd say this is probably related to MySQL's default transaction isolation level (REPEATABLE READ), but how exactly escapes me. As an ugly hack try issuing a  rollback in your get method before the queries and see what happens.

Comment: You should also add `db.session.add(vehicle)` before `commit`. In general, the modified data should be available immediately, it looks like your `put` operation is creating a hanging transaction that is not commited immediately. Also make sure there is no caching involved here.